# Why am i getting these errors

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsx

I am creating react app manually but when i do npm start i get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `node your-script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
```

There is likely additional logging output above.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abdul Mateen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-14T08_10_44_207Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The pieces of the error that you have included don't actually say what the error is. The parts _above_ `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` would be the actual error. Please include the full output from npm.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows:**

First do:

```
npm run clean
```

Then delete

`node_modules`

Then delete `package-lock.json` file too and run

```
npm install
```

Then in last

```
npm start
```

**For Linux:**

Step 1: 
`$ npm cache clean --force`

Step 2: delete node_modules

`$ rm -rf node_modules folder` or delete it manually

Step 3: Then

`npm install`
 And in last start again with

```
$ npm start
```

For granting root access you can use `sudo`

Hopes it Helps. Thanks

Comment: i tried this but nothing changes..I am getting same issue

Comment: Then First delete nodejs from path (C:\Program Files) also delete npm-cache and npm from path (C:\Users\windows\AppData\Roaming). Then try to re-install nodejs and run npm install